# Email is not sending when the script is running by CRON

Tags: ubuntu, cron, sendmail

I wrote the simple backup bash script and at the end of it, it's sending an email to me that backup is ready. Everything works perfect when I run this script from terminal (root), but when the script is running by CRON, email is not sending :-/.

```
#!/bin/sh
filename=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
backup_dir="/mnt/backup/"
email_from_name="BACKUP"
email_to="my@email"
email_subject="Backup is ready"
email_body_file="/tmp/backup-email-body.txt"

tar czf "$backup_dir$filename.tgz" "/home/www"

echo "Subject: $email_subject" > $email_body_file
ls $backup_dir -sh >> $email_body_file

sendmail -F $email_from_name  -t $email_to < $email_body_file
```

Comment: -t means extract recipients from message headers. -F sets the fullname of the sender and -f sets the envelope sender address.

Answer (score 2):

Cronjobs run in a minimal environment, so you can't even assume that `$PATH` is set correctly. The script is probably failing to find the `sendmail` executable. Set `$PATH` explicitly in the crontab to something like this, or specify the full path to `sendmail` in the script.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Comment: and after setting path add `export PATH` in the very next line

Comment: @adamo Not in crontabs.

Comment: Yep! I missed that part. Diagonally I assumed that you meant that he should set PATH in his script.

Comment: Yea! You're right! I changed "sendmail" to "/usr/sbin/sendmail" and it works perfect now! Thanks

Comment: You should accept this as the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

This is the environment issue , we need to set the env path in cron  as below

```
38 03 * * 5  /bin/ksh c ". /home/adcis/caliber/.profile ;
/home/xyz/abc/ABCD_BATCH/REPORT_ABC/amb_main_script.ksh" >> /home/xyz/abc/ABCD_BATCH/LOGS/output.txt
```